# Is there any means to do RAM memory testing for multi-core during another application using target memory domain

Tags: memory, arm

I try to implement ram test such like this url(http://www.esacademy.com/en/library/technical-articles-and-documents/miscellaneous/software-based-memory-testing.html) in dual core microcontroller.
This ram testing shall be available in the middle of another process. 
I think implementing this by using interrupt disable, but it is not appropriate.

As a precondition, My implementing ram test is supposed to do data backup to another domain before testing and to put these data back to initial address.
So, other driver can use same data as usual after RAM testing.

In this case I use interrupt disable, it's not available in dual core.
Because the both of cores access the same RAM domain and disabling interrupt
is not working another core's processing, there are only occurring data inconsistency.

Could you give me your idea?

Comment: I'm not ARM expert, so just general question. Does your memory-management-unit support virtual mapping? In that case maybe you can copy one page at time elsewhere, remap it so the process running on second core will keep using the same virtual addresses, test the memory page, move to next one (you can use the freshly tested one as target buffer for next page copy). You need still to freeze the other process while copying+remapping the memory page, so depending on your OS/process handling this may be tricky to do in synchronized consistent way.

Comment: Also if the other core is completely outside of your control (i.e. it can do it's own memory mapping, and the process in question is not user-land like app, but kernel space code), then there's probably no reasonable way to flip the pages on fly (without having access to sources of the other SW, and modifying it to allow for such synchronization/flipping). I can't think of method which would be completely independent (on OS support), I think the second independent core is too much to sync against without cooperation.

Comment: Maybe with some kind of HW debug or MMU features, making the tested memory page fail upon read/write for other process (except your test), so even if the interrupt occurs on other core, and the other code is being executed, it will just trap upon first read/write into that memory page, you can finish the copy + remap and try to recover by re-executing the last instruction of other process, this time on remapped memory already. But you still must be the top master of things in your system, to have this trap over anyone else. (and the other code must be not sensible to timing/pauses).

Comment: You can also try to minimize the stalls by introducing the write-trap first, then copy the memory page with trap interrupt just collecting changes, then freeze the other process, apply changes only, remap page, unfreeze... that will minimize the pause down to few additional memory writes.. it's still probably not good enough to strictest real-time response constraints, but may be good enough for anything else, even moving things like automotive/rockets, few microseconds may be just couple of cm/m movement.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Even though it might be insane what I say, I can't get support of OS and MMU. But your thinking is absolutely correct. MMU is need to be implemented by myself, and must make user and other driver always use it.  Processing speed is generally also important. Honestly, it make me nearly give up.

Comment: It's probably quite similar to what modern OS does while swapping the memory in/out from/to disk system, so that's why I think your solution can be drastically different if the process using that memory is user-like (and the OS-like code can tinker with it's memory map in synchronized way, freezing the process meanwhile), or kernel-like, then you will have to use all possible HW support to isolate that other process from accessing particular memory page while you are tampering with it and if there's one tiny way to operate that memory past your control, you are out of luck.

Comment: I will check its HW-Support.Fortunately, The type of architecture is Arm-Cortex-M7. So,there might be many materials. If all else fails, I will be changing jobs

Comment: Other approach involves the processes themselves to act also as mem-testers, they should allocate their memory in aligned page-blocks structures, write everything twice or three times, calculate checksums, store those in cross-way across different RAM modules and keeping some checksum probably in registers too, and validating them back by reading in spare idle time.. at that point the process itself has finest possible control over timing of tests, so it will not happen while some time critical thing is going on. But this is like when coding control code for rocket engine, or similar.

Comment: What exactly is your OS? Tweaking MMU on a Linux kernel is not hard at all. When you say “no support” — what do you even mean? And memory testing is nonsense without you having access to MMU. You never know what you test. The physical RAM your page is mapped to can be exchanged at any time without your knowledge. The test must assert that certain assumptions hold, otherwise it’s invalid. I presume that this is for a safety certification of some sort, and I speak here from the viewpoint of a reviewer of such code.

Comment: There are no OS, but OS(RTOS) is available by user-side. So, what I would like to say is OS make no sense. But, it is not problem in my understanding, because my environment is real-time(Cortex-R, Cortex-M), and it's basically accompanied by MMU. I need to avoid being caught by safety function requirements. As you said, there are necessary to build certain assumptions. 
Moreover, it is completely conflict.

Comment: Sorry, There are some typo. "it's basically accompanied by MMU" is replaced by "it's not basically accompanied by MMU"

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat by definition if you are running code on that ram you are not testing that ram if you want to do a memory test you need to be off the ram under test.

But that depends on what your definition of test is.  If it is a memory test to test the memory itself, cant be on it, you are not testing some of the memory so you are not testing the memory (looks like what your link is about, note links are bad in SO questions and answers, remote links are not assumed to remain active).

Cant test half then another half you are not testing the address bus completely.

If this is a performance test then ideally you want to be off of it and have the test run completely from cache.  Multi core helps for a targeted test as you can push the interface a little bit harder, difficult to max it out with a general purpose processor though, multi-core or not.

Otherwise if you just want to exercise a fraction then allocate a fraction and test it, in whatever way you wish.  Its not really a memory test though.

Sounds like from  your requirements you are not really interested in a full memory test, so do as much as you can to make your boss happy.

Actual memory testing a system is very much specific to that system, how you approach it, how you solve it.  You want that code(/stack) to not be on that ram, ideally the chip/system design includes a fast internal SRAM that you can use for board bring up and design verification, possibly manufacture test, but manufacture test should be testing the solder/board not all the bits in the ram, there are ways to do that too.  If no internal sram then they had to design some way to bring the system up, or not, if you can run from flash and have the cache on, and can map that out of the way of the DRAM address space, then you can test the dram(/external ram) that way (no stack, just the CPU registers, basically assembly language).

Comment: Thanks for your replying and I'm sorry for the confusion. In terms of conducting memory testing, that's correct. But it's actually a full memory test and it's already implemented. So,I need means to create memory protection by one　memory testing software that make no interference to other software processing.